# javascript and java regarding clock

Tags: java, javascript

I have q question regarding javascipt date, i follow the example in w3school to get the clock, and it will refresh automatically, it works fine but it show my local current time, which i dont want.

Instead i want it to show my server time, because the program will run in my server so in java if i put the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formatter.format(new java.util.Date())
```

It will actually get the server time. I wonder why the following code will get my locale time(my pc time, not my server time) even i change to    var t = d.toString();

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

Comment: Javascript runs client-side, hence displays client time...

Comment: your browser has no idea where your server is, nor does it need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder why the following code will get my locale time(my pc time, not my server time) even i change to var t = d.toString()

Because `d` is still a client-side JavaScript `Date` object, and both `toLocaleString` and `toString` return the time in the client's timezone.

If you want to show the server's time, you'll need to determine the delta between the client's timezone and the server's timezone and then apply that delta. One way of doing that which is *reasonably* precise, but not perfect, is to have your server-side code output JavaScript code that returns the server's time as of the page being sent from the server:

```
<script>
<% // Server-side code
    Calendar serverDate = Calendar.getInstance();
%>
var d = new Date(
    <%=serverDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)%>,
    <%=serverDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)%>,
    <%=serverDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)%>,
    <%=serverDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)%>,
    <%=serverDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)%>,
    <%=serverDate.get(Calendar.SECOND)%>
);
var delta = d.getTime() - Date.now();
</script>
```

Note how that's using JSP to output numbers to the JavaScript code. The browser will see something like this:

```
<script>
<% // Server-side code
    Calendar serverDate = Calendar.getInstance();
%>
var d = new Date(
    2014,
    11,
    23,
    9,
    54,
    27
);
var delta = d.getTime() - Date.now();
</script>
```

*(Note that I'm assuming a Gregorian or Julian calendar above; if so, `Calendar`'s month field will be 0 = January, which is what JavaScript expects.)*

The resulting `delta` is the difference, in milliseconds, between the server's time and the client's time, meaning that you can do this at any time on the client to show the *server's* time:

```
var d  = new Date(Date.now() - delta);
```

I *think* I have that the right way around. :-) If not, it'll be `+ delta`.

Comment: but value d from var d = new Date("<%=formatter.format(new Date())%>");   gives NaN value

Comment: @user3172596: Remember that the `<%=...%>` part is **server-side JSP code**. What you're sending to the browser will look something like `var d = new Date("2014-12-23 09:47:10");`, which will (on any modern browser) be parsed successfully. So you need to make sure the JSP part is working (or change it to whatever server-side rendering tech you're using).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—do not use strings. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` will be parsed as UTC by ES5 compliant browsers (e.g. Firefox, Safari) and local by ES6 browsers (e.g. Chrome). Pass a time value (e.g. UTC seconds since epoch) which will be reliably converted to the correct UTC time wherever the client is.

Comment: my jsp part is working fine, because in my html, i embedded jsp to it, it works fine 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

<%=formatter.format(new java.util.Date())%> 

Not sure why when do this var d = new Date("<%=formatter.format(new java.util.Date())%>");  will give me NaN

Comment: @u—"*my jsp part is working fine*" sure, but the client part isn't. Compare IE8, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, you're probably right, we should use the long form. But I don't think that's the OP's problem, I think they're just not getting the client/server separation right.

Comment: @RobG: Updated to use discrete fields (I hope -- haven't used `Calendar` in a long time), should have done that from the outset.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ur code ok but very weird issue, if i use - delta, it will show the wrong time but it refreshes every second, but if i use + delta the time is actually correct but it will keep refresh the same value, say if it is 10.30pm now, it will keep showing 10.30

Answer (score 0):

Because before `var t = d.toString()`, you assigned current date to `var d`. Instead pass server date in request and use it in javascript.

Comment: it is not same with java new java.util.Date()?

Comment: No. If you write `var d = new Date()` in javascript, it will run on client side and fetch local time. And that's why you are seeing current time

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will have to request the server time from the javascript using AJAX. Once the response is returned you will then be able to pass it into the date object as a string.

```
var date = new Date(dateString);
```

Using AJAX to get the server date:

First you have to build a page to display the current time. On the server build a java file to serve this in a file:

```
{"serverTime": "currentTimeString"}
```

Once that is being served from the file you created, use AJAX to request the file asynchronously. jQuery's $.ajax() method is a popular method of completing this; it has a promise method callback once the file has been fetched, placing the response in memory.

You can then decode the JSON String in the success callback like so:

```
function(response) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
    var currentTime = parsed.serverTime;
}
```

Comment: but my program will run in the server, using 
new java.util.Date(), i can display the current time, which is the server time

Comment: If you build a page/API call which returns that value in a standard such as JSON. You can decode it and store it in memory using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS uses the client timestamp because it's running on the client. If you want to use the server timestamp on the client you need to embed it in a server-rendered script or make a separate HTTP request for it.

Comment: Where "timestamp" is UTC seconds or milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. ;-)